# Plot time AM/PM in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a list with taxi rides over a 24h period.

On the first column, called 'start_time' I have the start date of the ride in format HH:MM:SS AM or HH:MM:SS PM. Example 12:00:02 AM, 16:06:50 PM etc.

I want to make a plot to have on the x-axis the Hours of the day and on the y-axis the price for each race, by plotting the 'ride_value' column.

[image]

Data is stored in .csv format and I load it in JupyterNotebook using pandas

I assume I need to do a sort of transformation but from what I've found, something like  taxi_data['hours'] = taxi_data['start_time'].dt.date doesn't work because it needs the data from 'start_time' to be in datetime format.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Also can you share a sample data?

Comment: can you confirm whether the column 'start_time' is a datetime column?

Comment: 'start_time' contains only date-type format as HH:MM:SS AM/PM.